# SQL contagem de dados filtrado por múltiplas tabelas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma página em PHP onde tenho que gerar um gráfico de "Vendedores cadastrados" filtrados por região.

O problema é que a tabela de Vendedores tem Id da cidade, a tabela de Cidade tem a Id de estado e a de estado tem Id de região. E eu preciso filtrar os **vendedores** por **região**.

Seguem as estruturas:

Tabela de Vendedores
[image: Tabela de Vendedores]
Tabela de Cidade
[image: Tabela de Cidade]
Tabela de Estado
[image: Tabela de Estado]
Tabela de Região
[image: Tabela de Região]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente, um grande `JOIN` resolve tudo:

```
select v.PrimeiroNome as "Nome do Vendedor", r.Nome as "Região"
from Vendedores v
inner join Cidades c on c.Id = v.IdCidade
inner join Estados e on e.Id = c.IdEstado
inner join Regionais r on r.Id = e.IdRegional;
```

Para contar:

```
select tabela.Nome as "Região", count(*) from
    (select v.PrimeiroNome as "Nome do Vendedor", r.Nome -- as "Região"
    from Vendedores v
    inner join Cidades c on c.Id = v.IdCidade
    inner join Estados e on e.Id = c.IdEstado
    inner join Regionais r on r.Id = e.IdRegional) tabela
-- group by "Região"; -- Isto aqui deu erro no Browser.
group by tabela.Nome
```

Comment: Eu cheguei a fazer mas não deu certo. Meu problema está em fazer a contagem de Vendedor (Tabela1) relacionado filtrado por Região (Tabela4) e depois agrupar tudo (group by).

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente no programa de consulta. Já marquei como correto, porém no Browser deu erro.
`Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference`
Saberia o que significa?

De qualquer forma muito obrigado.

Comment: Estranho ter dado isso. Atualizei novamente.